# Some errors while changing default currency in odoo 10.0...

Tags: odoo, currency, price, currency-exchange-rates

How to change the default currency in Odoo 10.0 without exchange rate ?

I tried the method from http://www.surekhatech.com/blog/change-currency-in-pos-in-odoo-10

But I got the errors such as

1. When in POS, I tried to "Validate Closing & Post Entries", I got Odoo warning There is no account defined on the journal Cash for Profit involved in a cash difference and can not post the POS transaction.
2. While in POS checkout, the unsolved problems on https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/10-0-a-transaction-can-t-have-a-0-amount-none-error-on-validate-odoo-pos-payment-121554

How to fix them ?

I also includeed the recorded screen on youtube at :   https://youtu.be/IahubLwnDDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solution of your 1st error you need to define opening and closing account in payment methods define in POS front. For that **POS >> Configuraion >> Payment Methods.** In that choose payment method which active in POS and from that there are 2 fields name "**Default Debit Account**" and "**Default Credit Account**" define accounts here. By adding accounts here your 1st error is resolved. Don't know much about second error if you know then late me know. :)